# poptrox jQuery plugin and iframe set to fullscreen

Tags: jquery, iframe, plugins, fullscreen

I used jQuery poptrox plugin, to display video in an iframe. It works, but doesn't allow fullscreen. Can someone help me?

**Here is my code:**

```
<a href="'.$v->video.'" data-poptrox="iframe,600x400" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">+</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

by default poptrox plugin inserts video into an iframe. So I changed data-poptrox type to youtube, and the fullscreen now works.

```
<a  href="'.$v->video.'" data-poptrox="youtube,600x400" >+</a>
```